# Using variable arrays in models

Tags: sql-server, dbt

Is it possible to define an array in the vars section and use it inside the SQL syntax of a model?

Something like this

**dbt_project.yml:**

```
vars:
  active_country_codes: ['it','ge']
```

**model.sql**

```
SELECT ... 
  FROM TABLE WHERE country_code IN ('{{ var("active_country_codes") }}')
```

I've tried with a single value, i.e:**['it']**, and works but if I add another it starts failing.

I am using the SQL Server Data connector.

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2019 for testing in local, Azure SQL Server for the production environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that you are writing is correct. You just need to pass the variable as a string with a comma also as a string character.

```
vars:
  active_country_codes: 'it'',''ge'
```

You can do something like this :

```
SELECT ... 
  FROM TABLE WHERE country_code IN ('{{ var("active_country_codes") }}')
```

And it will create query for you like this:

```
SELECT ... 
  FROM TABLE WHERE country_code IN ('it,'ge')
```

I have tested this and it's working fine. I'm using Bigquery Connection but it shouldn't matter as it's dbt generation.

Comment: You are right, this works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Great, Happy to help!!

Answer (score 1):

My educated guess is that the result of `{{ var("active_country_codes") }}` is to insert a comma separated string.  In that case, you'll need a string splitting function.  You will have to roll your own if you haven't already, unless you have SQL Server 2016 or later.  Then you can use `string_split`.  Below is code using it.     I use the `exists` approach as opposed to `in` due to performance.

```
select    ...
from      table t
where     exists (
              select   0
              from     string_split('{{ var("active_country_codes") }}', ',') ss
              where    t.country_code = ss.value
          )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've favoured pkd's answer as it requires no modification in the model's code (i.e. not using the string_split function).

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
vars:
   var_name: "'one','two','three'"
```

```
where field_name in ({{ var("var_name") }})
```

Looks a little bit clearer than:

```
  active_country_codes: 'it'',''ge'
```